# Targeting a select box inside the header of a table

Tags: jquery

The code below works fine **without** the **table** tags. With the table tags I am unable to figure the right approach to reference the select checkbox.  So basically the 'select' in $('select') has to be changed to something else for this to work which I can't figure out. Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

```
<table>
    <form id= "Cars" action="" method="post" >
        <th>
        CARS: <select name="ddcars" id="ppcars" >
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">Toyota</option>
            <option value="2">Nissan</option>
            </select> 
        </th>
    </form>


    <form id="trucks" action="" method="post">
        <th>
        TRUCKS : <select name="ddtrucks" id="pptrucks" >
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">TATA</option>
            <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        </select> 
        </th>
    </form>
</table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            $(this).parent('form').submit();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your html structure is not correct. It should be in this hierarchy  table > tr > td > form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have one `select` then `$('select')` should work fine.

however, you have malformed HTML

**this is wrong**

```
<table>
    <form id= "Cars" action="" method="post" >
        <th>
        CARS: <select name="ddcars" id="ppcars" >
```

**this is correct**

```
<table>
  <th>
    <form id= "Cars" action="" method="post" >
            CARS: <select name="ddcars" id="ppcars" >
```

if you use the above hierarchy, `$(this).parent('form').submit();` is correct, too.

**Working Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5qtLu3pk/

Comment: Thanks Ted ! what a silly mistake that was and it ate away my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is not element `tr`. `table` need `tr` and than `th`.
2. Element `table` cannot contain element `form`. Put `form` inside
   `th`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <form id= "Cars" action="" method="post" >
        CARS: <select name="ddcars" id="ppcars" >
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Toyota</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        </select> 
      </form>
    </th>

    <th>
      <form id="trucks" action="" method="post">
        TRUCKS : <select name="ddtrucks" id="pptrucks" >
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">TATA</option>
        <option value="2">Nissan</option>
        </select> 
      </form>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
      $(this).parent('form').submit();
    }); 
  });
</script>
```